# null && minWidth >= 0.0': is not true error when using a SingleChildScrollView

Tags: flutter

I have a `RoundedLoadingButton` in a `SingleChildScrollView`. There are 2 issues.
1: the bottom of the button is cut off (see the bottom shadow)
2: When I click the button or the button becomes a loader, an error pops up on the screen.

I tried adding an `Expanded` widget to the `Column` and `RoundedLoadingButton`, but nothing changed. I also tried changing the `mainAxisSize` of the column to min and max, but they both didn't help.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

```dart
return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
        child: Form(
          child:  Column(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(height: Constants.verticaleSectionSpacing * 2),
                    TextFormField(),
                    TextFormField(),
                    TextFormField(),
                    RoundedLoadingButton(
                      height: 45,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      controller: saveBtnController,
                      child: Text('Save'),
                      onPressed: _doSomething,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: @UlaşKasım Um... isn't that what I have??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can change `width` from `double.infinity` to `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` or a fixed number like 300

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rounded_loading_button/rounded_loading_button.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
          child: Form(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                //SizedBox(height: Constants.verticaleSectionSpacing * 2),
                TextFormField(),
                TextFormField(),
                TextFormField(),
                RoundedLoadingButton(
                  height: 45,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  //controller: saveBtnController,
                  child: Text('Save'),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! What's the diff between: `double.infinity` and `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width`? Also, the bottom shadow is still cut off on my end

Comment: I have checked RoundedLoadingButton' source code and discover when use width with double.infinity has this problem. sorry I do not know the bottom shadow cut off issue.

Comment: Glad to help. please upvote this answer if it helps you. thanks.